# Impact of table compression on HA Synchronous-commit mode scenarios

Tags: sql-server-2014, high-availability, compression

I am working with a HA SQL 2014 instance with Synchronous-commit mode.

I did some table compression analysis with sp_estimate_data_compression_savings and I learned that table compression can be very beneficial for the overall performance. My servers have very powerful CPU setup.

However, It is unknown to me how table compression impacts a HA Synchronous-commit instance. My guess is that since data is compressed, it makes it easier for Synchronous-commit mirroring.

What is the impact of table compression on HA Synchronous-commit mode scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using AGs for 3 years now, with table compression, and have not seen any material impact.

The data shunted between the servers is all log transport, and that itself is compressed, the compression of the pages themselves doesn't really factor in. Your only concern would be if you were under CPU pressure already and then added on that little extra for the table compression.